# linear regression model prediction in scikit-learn is inconsistent

Tags: python, scikit-learn

So I built a simple linear regression model with a handful of features.  When I try to predict for new input, the output is inconsistent.  For example:

```
In [1]: model.predict(X_new)
Out[1]: array([  7.15993216e+08,   1.13548305e+09])
```

But if I tack it onto the original training sample, I get a very different answer:

```
In [2]: model.predict(X_training[:1].append(X_new))[1:]
Out[2]: array([  272682.59925699,  1179906.89475647])
```

This seems to be model agnostic (at least within linear regression).  I also tried the same inside of a pipeline and get the sam behavior.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What exactly is the type of `X_training`? You'd usually pass an `np.array` object there, but that doesn't have an `append` method.

Comment: It's a pandas data frame but it's the same issue with a numpy array.

Comment: @SohierDane, I'm actually pulling the first value of X_training and then, from the predicted results, pulling all but the first value (so that the prediction for the training value doesn't show).  Should be the same output I think.

Comment: @SohierDane it shouldn't matter because prediction should be performed line-by-line.  So the output should be identical.

Comment: Sorry, I was having a dyslexic moment and reading your code as model.fit_predict() not model.predict. Deleting my prior comments as unhelpful.

Comment: @user6656013 Are you 100% postive that X_trainig[0] == X_new[0]? If not, you're predicting on different things...so different results.

Comment: @aberger `X_trainig[0] != X_new[0]`, that's the whole point.  I'm adding a single line to the input and the entire output changes.

Comment: @user6656013 I'm not sure what the issue is then. A different test set should product a different prediction. It may help to see what X_training and X_new look like and how you are training the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with the sorting order of the pandas data frame.  A solution for this is to pre-sort both training and testing data sets by the same column order.  Something along the lines of:

```
model.fit(np.array(X_training.sort_index(1)))
model.predict(np.array(new_input.sort_index(1)))
```

This cements the column order in the training and testing arrays.